# JSONP query to WebApp from Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, jsonp

I am writing a Chrome extension that needs to query a WebApp I have deployed from the scripting utility on a Google Spreadsheet. The WebApp needs to send it a JSON item (array). The query comes from the background script of the Chrome extension.

It is my understanding that Chrome can handle JSON from a different domain with explicit permission, which I've provided in the manifest. I'm using the following code in the WebApp at the end of doGet(), where output is a string containing my JSON object:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"hello": 1, "beep": 2}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

When I query the WebApp it works fine.

In background.js, I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      URL, //contains my URL with appropriate parameters
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The background console is returning nothing -- no errors, but no success either. I've tried using the success, error and complete callbacks. I have a console.log() call before and after the ajax call, and the one before fires while the one after does not, so clearly something is going awry in this call. But again, background console shows nothing.

I also tried this in synchronous and asynchronous modes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I do similar and works for an extension i own calling an apps script .
I instead return regular json from the content script, which is published anonymous.
In the manifest of your extension you need to add two url permissions, one for the script app  url and aNother for the resulting redirect to googleusercontent url.

Comment: I realized, btw, that I don't need to use JSONP -- Chrome extensions can make cross-domain requests with explicit permission, as you pointed out. It still doesn't work though. (edited post above to reflect changes)

Comment: how is the service published, post all options.